# why arent placeholders not working?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, placeholder

```
testMsg.toEmail = @"%@@txt.att.net", phoneNumberEntry.text;
```

hi so i want to make testMsg.toEmail to be (phoneNumberEntry text)@txt.att.net. I tried doing it with placeholders but it didn't work. how do i fix?

Comment: Your previous question uses `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]` - that might be useful here :-)

Comment: I tried [NSString stringWithFormat phoneNumberEntry] and [NSString stringWithFormat phoneNumberEntry.text]. neither of them worked

Comment: sorry. it doesn't successfully send the email. I know the frameworks worth though because I switched testMsg.toEmail to a string of my email, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think Martin is right you can use this code-:

```
testMsg.toEmail =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@txt.att.net",phoneNumberEntry.text];
```

Comment: btw phoneNumberEntry is a text field. also, the message didn't send when I tried the above code.

Comment: @DaniM.Smith Use NSLog(testMsg.toEmail) to check the content of textMsg.toEmail after this statement, see what you get. Good if you can post the relevant code segment too as there may be other issues elsewhere.